Is it possible to get a mesh to appear behind a specific object?
Here I'm using a reverse hull method to create an outline for this object, though I'd like for the mesh to appear behind the cat as shown here.

I'm aware this could be done with render layers but I'd like to have this work realtime (In the viewport).
Effect I get:

